# -(IBAction) not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, ibaction

Im trying to make, when buttons is pressed it will go to next page here is the code, but there is nothing happening. I put breakpoint to see if it getts there and it does. At some point it was working then something magically happend and now it doesn't work anymore. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
    //
//  MainViewController.m
//  SimpleApp
//
//  Created by Ruslan on 1/28/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "EditViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController



// Call this when take photo button is pressed





- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Show Camera




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}


// Call this when ipmport button is pressed

-(IBAction)importButton:(id)sender
{
    EditViewController *editPage = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editPage animated:(YES)];
//    EditViewController *editPage = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editPage animated:(YES)];

}



@end
```

Comment: Did you add the IBAction to an Button in Xib or Mainstorybord.

Comment: Given that IBAction doesn't do anything, how can you tell it's not working?

Comment: When i run on device or simulator nothing happens by press of a button

Comment: check to see if self.navigationController is nil.  That's only populated if your ViewController is inside a nav controller.

Comment: make sure that the connection for that button action to the IBAction exists. It could be possible that you renamed the method, and the connection was undone because of that

Comment: The connection is there. But im not sure how do i check is self.navigationController is nil

Comment: set a breakpoint and look at it in the debugger; or add a NSLog(@"nav = %@", self.navigationController);

Comment: Just checked and its null  self.navigationController (null)

Comment: Yup.  So there's your problem.  If you send messages to a nil object, they're just ignored.  Did you switch from nav controller to tab bar or something?

Comment: @Dave no i haven't. Any ideas what should i do? Thanks

Comment: Select your viewcontroller in Interface Builder, then pick "Editor" -> "Embed In" -> "Navigation Controller".  That might do the trick.  Whatever is presenting the 'parent' view needs to present it within a nav controller, then you can "push" the new screen on (and get the 'back' arrow & title).

Comment: @Dave thanks for the help, but im not sure what i have to do in interface builder. Im new to this sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
[self presentViewController:editPage animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Alternatively, you need to think about how your views fit together.  Is the edit page supposed to be "pushed" from the view with the button (so it gets a 'back' arrow)?  If yes, then the view holding the button needs to be inside a nav controller, which means whoever is presenting *that* view would wrap it as a nav, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. Thanks to everyone for help i really appreciated

Comment: cool.  If that solves your problem you can mark the answer as accepted.  Suggest you google "UINavigationController Tutorial" and work through some examples, will be fun and give you a better grasp of this stuff.

Comment: Thanks again! Ill do some tutorials